# Internal SSD + External SSD (via firewire) RAID 1 and boot drive version control (like system-wide git)

Tags: ssd, external-hard-drive, raid, git

I was thinking in a theoretical realm about a certain use case, and was wondering if anybody has ever experienced anything like this.

If I were to set up my internal SSD and an external SSD (connected via SATA to Firewire) as a RAID 1 set, they would be mirrors of each other, independently bootable.

What I was wondering is would there be any way to separate them and work with them independently (causing the two drives to diverge), and then when I bring them back together, do some sort of merge of my work from each to a new synchronized state.

I don't necessarily think that this would be feasible if they both diverge, but I think that a merge like --ours or --theirs in git, accepting the state of one of the drives to be the new state for both could be possible.

This would enable you to do work on your laptop, sync your drives using RAID, and then if you wanted you could leave your laptop at home, take just your external somewhere where you know there will be a machine (like work or school) get work done, and then when you return to your laptop, "fast-forward" your internal to the new state of the external with all the work you did that day.

Comment: Why is `independently boot-able` a requirement? My personal solution would be to simply do work on the main disk, SyncToy to the external disk, use external disk on another machine, upon plugging it back into the main machine then use SyncToy to go in the other direction. Not sure what kind of work you do such as video editing or programming but maybe a cloud-storage solution is what you really need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it seems that you don't want a RAID. You just want a software for syncing data.

Second, `git` is not good for big binary files. I would go for `rsync` or some top level `rsync` based program. Other top level alternatives are `btsync` or `syncthing`, but they are more likely to be used over networks or remote hosts. Anyway they can do the job.

Comment: I read through my original post again, and it does indeed seem like I was talking about using git due to all of the git references.  I fully understand that git is not a feasible system-wide sync option.  I've used rsync quite a bit, and indeed I agree this should fulfill the use case I described.The RAID 1 idea was perhaps a bit convoluted.

Comment: Then maybe rsync with the --update option should do the trick. You could try to make a bidirectional little script that does the sync. Also there are a lot of front-ends for rsync and rdiff, although I haven't used them. Thanks for the rep!